# highchart, TypeError: obj is null

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, json, highcharts

I want to use PHP to request a datetime variable from html,

and use the variable to SELECT data from mysql database.Then make a json to generate highchart.

It successfully generate the json but didnt generate the highchart.

And I use Firebug it says TypeError: obj is null

Here is my code
PHP

```
<?php
   header('Content-type: application/json');
   $con = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
   mysql_select_db("project", $con);
    $month=$_REQUEST['select_month'];

   $sqlChart_Q="SELECT T,value FROM `Temperature`WHERE month(T)='$month'";
   $sqlChart_R=mysql_query($sqlChart_Q);
   while($arrChart_ROW=mysql_fetch_array($sqlChart_R)) {
        $time=strtotime($arrChart_ROW[0])*1000;
          $temp=(float)$arrChart_ROW[1];     
   $arrChart[]=array("time" => $time,"value" => $temp);
    }
    echo json_encode($arrChart);
     ?>
```

and js

```
     var chart;
     $(document).ready(function() {           
     var options = {
        chart: {
           renderTo: 'month',
           type: 'spline',
        },
        title: {
        },
        xAxis: {
           type: 'datetime'

        },
        yAxis: {
        },
        series: [{
           name: 'Temperature',
           data: [] 
        }] 
        };
        $.getJSON('PHP/db_month.php', function(json) {
        temp = [];
        $.each(json, function(key,value) {
        temp.push([value.time,value.value]);
              });         
        options.series[0].data = temp;           
        chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
        });
```

json ( select_month=5; $month=$_REQUEST['select_month'])

```
[{"time":1400076317000,"value":50},{"time":1400076322000,"value":25},{"time":1400076327000,"value":34},{"time":1400110911000,"value":50},{"time":1400110916000,"value":43},{"time":1400110919000,"value":75},{"time":1400110920000,"value":35},{"time":1400110922000,"value":46},{"time":1400110924000,"value":66},{"time":1400110925000,"value":73},{"time":1400113566000,"value":20},{"time":1400161118000,"value":55},{"time":1400186496000,"value":50},{"time":1400193165000,"value":43},{"time":1400196532000,"value":50}]
```

By the way, when the sql function change to

```
    SELECT T,value FROM `Temperature`WHERE month(T)='5'
```

it will successfully generate the highchart which data is create in MAY.

(PS:type of T is timestamp, I don't know isn't it matter.

What's wrong with my code?
Can someone help me solve this problem.
Thanks you very much !!

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK in the json_encode function, because you return strings, instead of numbers.

Comment: When I set as `echo json_encode($arrChart,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);`
It show `Warning:json_encode() expects exactly 1 parameter, 2 given on line 20

Comment: Sorry, it was because my PHP version is too old. Now I update to new version and `echo json_encode($arrChart,JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` works,
but still no highchart

Comment: It looks like you have old PHP, so in your case you need to use loop and parseFloat() function on json to convert string into number.

Answer (score 0):

The variable $arrChart is not defined when your query returns an empty set. You have to define this variable before cycle.

```
$arrChart = array();
```

Also your sql query isn't secure. You have to write something like this:

```
$sqlChart_Q = "SELECT T,value FROM `Temperature`WHERE month(T)=" . (int) $month;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!
When I add `$arrChart = array();`in PHP,the highchart is generated
but without the data.

Comment: It happens because your query doesn't return any data. Try to check: if (empty($_REQUEST['select_month']). By the way, using $_REQUEST variable isn't a good idea. You have to use $_GET array (because $.getJSON load data using a GET HTTP request).

Comment: There is a mistake in your js code. You don't send a select_month value. Try this: $.getJSON('PHP/db_month.php', {select_month: your_month_value}, function(json) {...});

Comment: Thanks for your reply!! I change $_REQUEST['select_month'] to $_GET['select_month']                                                
AND I am sure that $_REQUEST['select_month'] is not null because it can successfully generate json.                                         
Can I ask you why $.getJSON('PHP/db_month.php', {select_month: your_month_value}, function(json) {...})
and what your_month_value mean?  thanks you very much

Comment: NOW I know what does `$.getJSON('PHP/db_month.php', {select_month: your_month_value}, function(json)` mean. But could your_month_value be a variable from php??

Comment: No your_month_value is js variable. For example: $('#your_selectbox_id').val();

Comment: Can I get this variable(your_month_value) form html ?